# Returning a Java Vector from Server to Client using RMI

Tags: java, exception, rmi, unmarshalling

I'm new to RMI and I was trying to return a vector of a user-defined class to the client. I am getting an unmarshal exception.

[Here is my code.](http://pastebin.com/9E8NWkZb)

The exception I'm getting is:-

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
            java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Text
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at HelloServerImplementation_Stub.viewTexts(Unknown Source)
            at HelloClient.main(HelloClient.java:30)
    Caused by: java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException: Text
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.unmarshalValue(Unknown Source)
            ... 3 more
    Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Text
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeArray(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.access$300(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$PutFieldImpl.writeFields(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFields(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.Vector.writeObject(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
            at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.marshalValue(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
            at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Dont' post exceptions and other material elsewhere. Matter that forms part of a question must be included in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason of exception is

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: Text
                at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
```

Implement `Serializable` interface in your `Text` class.

```
class Text implements Serializable{

}
```